# Cloud Ubuntu server(Ubuntu 16.04) tar: This does not look like a tar archive

Tags: server, cloud, tar, ubuntu-16.04

I used the cloud Ubuntu server(Ubuntu 16.04). 
I used the following command to get data following the instruction from this link(https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/     Get The Pascal VOC Data ).
The Linxu command is shown as following:

```
curl -O http://pjreddie.com/media/files/VOCtrainval_11-May-2012.tar
curl -O http://pjreddie.com/media/files/VOCtrainval_06-Nov-2007.tar
curl -O http://pjreddie.com/media/files/VOCtest_06-Nov-2007.tar
tar xf VOCtrainval_11-May-2012.tar
```

but there is error:

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

and

```
$ file VOCtest_06-Nov-2007.tar
VOCtest_06-Nov-2007.tar: HTML document, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Could you tell me how to solve it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah, this may have resulted from the move from http -> https. I fixed it on the site, replace http with https and it'll work

Comment: hi @pireddie, there is the same issue for : curl -O http://pjreddie.com/media/files/voc_label.py, please fix it!